# Getting string within a string c

Tags: c, string, recursion

I want to get a string contained within a string where every time I see `(xxx)`
I will get only `xxx`.

I am trying to do it in a recursive manner with a function `int find(char* str)` for example.

The function will return `1` if there are no `'('` or `')'` left (all removed), and `0` otherwise.

the string can remain as is, just need to check the stated conditions.

OK input:  `(xxx)(zzz(yyy)zzz)`

BAD input: `xx(x(zzz)(y`

How can this be done in C?

Comment: What have you tried? It's trivial with a basic loop and `string.h` functions.

Comment: I really dont know how to handle this..

Comment: Suppose the input string is `a(xxx(yyyy)zzzzz)bb`, what do you want to see?  Can the input string be mangled or do you need to return a copy of the relevant segment of the string?  If the latter, you'll need to worry about memory management.  Also, when you've answered for that string, what about `a)xxx)yyyy(zzzzz(bb`?  How were we to know from your original question?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry, i edited the question.

Comment: Your edit makes very limited sense: '_The function will return 1 if there are no open or close parentheses left (all removed), and 0 otherwise.  The string can remain as is; just need to check the stated conditions._'  This is almost contradictory.  Are you looking for balanced matching parentheses?

Comment: Show us your `find` function that you have, and we can help improve it.   But if you're asking "How can this be done?", it might as well be "Plz send teh codez".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i edited it so you can see good and bad input, but in general, yes. this is what i need.

Comment: Isn't this is as simple as 'Count the number of open parentheses as you scan the string; decrement the count for close parentheses. If the count goes negative, or if the count is not zero at the end, return 1; otherwise return 0'.  And the function name should be 'int has_balanced_parentheses(char const *str);`?

Comment: @abelenky i dont know how to handle string manipulations in c, and i dont exactly know how to do it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler please look a the OK input and BAD input

Comment: OK input: +1 at '(', 0 at ')', +1 at '(', +2 at '(', +1 at ')', 0 at ')'; EOS.  Count is zero, return OK.  BAD input: +1 at '(', +2 at '(', +1 at ')', +2 at '('; EOS.  Count is not zero, return FAIL.  No recursion necessary.  If your exercise is in recursion, then on each '(', you call your code recursively to find the matching ')', returning two bits of data: where to resume the search and whether you ran into a problem (a close parenthesis without a matching open parenthesis, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple stack is a good way to solve this. Every time you see a '(' push onto the stack. Every time you see a ')' pop off the stack. If you ever try to pop off an empty stack or have things left on the stack when you are done, then the input was bad.

Edit: you could also do the same thing with a counter. Increment and decrement respectively. If the counter ever goes negative, return false. Otherwise, when you are done return true if you are at 0, or false otherwise. So the counter just represents the size of the 'stack'.

Answer (score 5):

I think this could be the answer, continuing the previous from abelenky:

```
int find(char *str)
{
  int pars = 0, pos = 0;
  while(str[pos] != 0) {
    if (str[pos] == '(') pars++;
    if (str[pos] == ')') pars--;
    if (pars < 0) return 0;        // closes before opens -> end here
    pos++;
  }
  if (pars != 0) return 0;         // not matched result
  else return 1;                   // matched result
}
```

Comment: Rather than an `if` statement, you could simply do `return !pars;` or `return (pars == 0);`. Either of these will guarantee 0 or 1 return value.

Comment: Right, and some other variations, like `return (pars==0)?1:0;`